# RegEx: how to find whether a text begins with currency symbols?

Tags: regex

I would like to check whether a given text begins with some currency symbols, like $€£¥. how to achieve that using regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your language, but something like `^[\$€£¥].*`

`[]` is a character group matching one of the characters inside.

You might have to write `\$` because the `$`-sign has sometimes special meaning in regexps.

`.*` matches "everything else" (except a newline).

Edit: After re-reading your question: If you really want to match *some currency symbols* (maybe more than one), try `^[\$€£¥]+.*`

Comment: Don't forget the ^ to indicate start of text, and a currency value will typically only have one currency symbol

Comment: You missed "^" at the beggining because @Sri wants to know if that chars in begining of the text

Comment: Thank you, I added `^`, and yep, you're correct, that a currency value usually has just one currency symbol, but Sri just wanted to check whether a string begins with a currency symbol.

Comment: inside character classes `$` doesn't require escaping.

Comment: Worth mentioning that in some cultures, the currency symbol **follows** the numbers, rather than preceding them.

Answer (score 1):

Which regex flavor?  If it's one that supports Unicode properties, you can use this:

```
^\p{Sc}
```

(I didn't add quotes or regex delimiters because I don't know which flavor you're using.)